# Output of one jenkins job needs to be passed as input to another jenkins job

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have a 1st Jenkins job which generates some report in the form of HTM (rows and columns). I have to fetch required values from the report and pass as input parameter for 2nd jenkin job. How can this be done?

Comment: Can you sow what have you tried thus far?

Comment: HTML is really for presentation of data, and is not an ideal format for transferring data to be used for later analysis. Certainly output your HTML as a human-readable report, but I would look at using another format for passing the data on instead... eg. XML, JSON or CSV.

Comment: okay now I have a report in the form of csv file. I have to fetch some data on required condition ,where to write that condition(is it on jenkin backend) and after that how will I pass fetched data as input parameters to 2nd job?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins jobs have their "workspace" configured as a default inside /workspace/ on the server/slave where your are executing the job.

What you can do is generate the output and store it in "workspace" of 1st job and access this path in 2nd job.

Workspace is a default location where output of the job is placed. However, this is totally configurable.

If you only want some values from report and not entire report, get the values and store it in some property file and configure "build downstream job" to load parameters from the mentioned property file.